# get joomla registration form variables?

Tags: joomla, registration

I'm working on getting joomla registration form values that user enters
at the time of registration. After two days of searching I reached to the 
file **Joomla2.5.7\components\com_users\controllers\registration.php**. In the register() method I 
tried to echo $data and $requestData variables but didn't see any output, on registering a new entry. I also tried to echo javascript but was unsuccessful. I'm trying to connect joomla database with my own database, so that whenever new user registers , he is also registered to my website. How can I get the registration form variables, any kind of help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty this

On registration controller you can find a function call to model like this

```
$return = $model->register($data);
```

after that just

```
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($data);
```

Also in the registration model
components\com_users\model\registration.php

register() method is defined you can check that for more info.

In addition if you want to add the users info to the other DB like your website DB.
The best place to write mysql query is :

```
            // Store the data.
        if (!$user->save()) {
            $this->setError(JText::sprintf('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_SAVE_FAILED', $user->getError()));
            return false;
        }else{

                  //Your custom mysql query to other DB or tables
            }
```

find the above section in the registration model inside register()method.

Hope this may solve your problem..

Comment: under components\com_users\model\registration.php inside that functions else part.

Comment: but remember its a joomla core file change so if you plan for joomla update Keep these kind of changes in details note.. Good luck

Comment: I tried to print_r($data) but it is not printing anything on the screen. when I echo $form it is printing code when user is registered

Answer (score 0):

I hope this tutorial helps you. You will find it explains the process of joomla registration form very well.

http://youtu.be/2AyCzb2vTaU